# pdfBox 2.0.3 Search for a element in a pdf

Tags: java, search, pdfbox

Is it possible to search a PDF file and look for an element, using the DEBUG tool the element I am looking for is a graphic line which in debug code looks like this:

```
q
0 0 0 RG
1.5 w
36 682.2 m
576 682.2 l
S
Q
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546071/extract-stream-dump-from-pdf-body-with-pdfbox

Comment: While the answer referenced by @TilmanHausherr shows how to access the immediate page content, there are multiple other content carrying objects (form xobjects, patterns, annotations). Retrieving their content is similarly easy but still slightly different.